# pull the data from mysqli to dropdown list php

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been trying to pull the data from database mysqli in the drop down menu. Here is my code for postad.html. I want to pull categories data from categories table with a row name CatName. I also have CatId that shows ctegory id. Thank you in advance.Please help:

```
<html>
       <head>
           <title>Post AD</title>
    </head>
  <body>

      <form method="POST" action="postad.php">

     <table>
    <tr>
    <td>AdName:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="adname"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>AdCategory</td>
         <td>
             //dropdown list
  <select name="Categories">
      <?php include = connect.php 

            $sql = "SELECT CatName FROM categories order by CatName";
            $result = $db->query($sql);
            while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {

        echo "<option value='". $row['CatName']."'>."</option>'; 
   }
    ?>

</select>
  </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>Contact Number</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="contactnumber"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>Image</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="image"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="description"></td>
     </tr>
        <tr>
    <td>Expiration Date</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="expirationdate"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td id="btn"><input type="submit" value='submit' name="submit"></td>
    </tr>    
    </table>     
    </form>
      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"Here is my code for postad.html"* - and you have PHP/SQL inside it. Plus, you're also missing a semi-colon `<?php include = connect.php` <= and quotes too. `<?php include 'connect.php';` minus the `=`

Comment: very difficult to answer that one... what is not happening? is there anything in the database? what about include = connect.php ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have an error with your menu code. Should be this

```
 echo "<option value=". $row['CatName'] ."></option>';
```

> Opposed to

```
 echo "<option value='". $row['CatName']."'>."</option>';
```

The result from the table is going to be a string regardless so there is no need to worry about value=''. The real problem was how you muffled up your quotes.

EDIT: Just noticed `include = connect.php` should be `include 'connect.php';`

```
<?php
$mysql_host = '';
$mysql_user = '';
$mysql_pass = '';
$mysql_dbase = '';
$mysql_table = '';
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $mysql_host . ';dbname=' . $mysql_dbase, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass);
$sth = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `' . $mysql_table . '` ORDER BY `id` CatName');
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
foreach ($result as $row) {?>
    <option value=<?php echo $row['CatName']; ?>></option>; 
<?}?>
```

Comment: Awesome...thank you....but still the data is not fetched.. the dropdown box is completely empty now....

Comment: Is there a way that I can write the select code in some php file and fetch it in the dropdown box in the html file??

Comment: Edited my post. I just wrote you something to copy paste and fill in the blanks, your `while` loop wasn't really applicable for what you wanted to do.

Comment: I recommend writing the options trxt and omitting the value attribute instead of what this answer does.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<option value='". $row['CatName']."'>."</option>';
```

contains error and also there is no inner html for options

You can use this way for simplicity.

```
$CatName=$row["CatName"];
echo '<option value="'.$CatName.'">'.$CatName.'</option>';
```

Comment: It is never necessary to duplicate the option tag's text as the value attribute -- you can safely omit the redundant value attribute declaration entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Now I have created a new php file called getcategories.php. and this page works well. Here is the code for it:

```
            $sql = "SELECT CatName FROM categories order by CatName";
            $result = $db->query($sql);
            $options="";
//echo "<select value='categories'>";       
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $categoryname=$row["CatName"]; 

   // echo '<option value="'.$categoryname.'">'.$categoryname.'</option>'; 

   // echo "</select>";
   //echo "$categoryname\n";
       $options .= '<option value="'.$categoryname.'">'.$categoryname.'</option>';

}
?>
```

How should I pull the data of options to the dropdown of html file

Comment: It is never necessary to duplicate the option tag's text as the value attribute -- you can safely omit the redundant value attribute declaration entirely.